# Audio on Ubuntu Linux Azure VM

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machines, ubuntu-18.04, audio

I have been trying to install alsa (using a simple sudo apt-get install alsa alsa-tools) in a Linux Virtual Machine on Azure (Ubuntu 18 LTS) but I'm having this error:

```
Loading new oem-audio-hda-daily-0.201808050301~ubuntu18.04.1 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.15.0-1037-azure
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-1037-azure
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms.0.crash'
Error!  Build of snd-hda-codec-idt.ko failed for: 4.15.0-1037-azure (x86_64)
```

After going around I'm not sure it is definitely a blocker because how the VM on Azure is created (Building initial module for 4.15.0-1037-azure) or  it is because I should use a different source or repo, or even a different approach

Comment: What is at that named path? Have you looked at it?

Comment: This is a complete log https://gist.github.com/judavi/9fac3798c0f2dcff7861a1d984dbecd5

Comment: I think I would install the package it is asking for, first.